# Do probabilistic sentiment lexica exist?

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I am aware of polarity and emotion lexica that give either a score or a classification as if the score or classification were known. But are there any lexica that for each term or phrase gives the *probability* that it is in a particular sentiment class, and for each of the classes in a particular grouping (e.g., pos/neg, various emotions)? Thank you!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551262/training-data-for-sentiment-analysis